# How to browse image in android app .?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application which is running on desktop fine .There is  one button on my desktop app in which it open the gallary select image.
But when I run that app on webview what will happen when I clcik that button .? will it open our mobile image gallary .?

Answer (score 0):

I created a small open source Android Library Project that streamlines this process, while also providing a **built-in file explorer** (in case the user does not have one present). It's extremely simple to use, requiring only a few lines of code.

You can find it at GitHub: [aFileChooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser).

If you want the user to be able to choose any file in the system, you will need to include your own file manager, or advise the user to download one. I believe the best you can do is look for "openable" content in an `Intent.createChooser()` like this:

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You would then listen for the selected file's `Uri` in `onActivityResult()` like so:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file 
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
            // Get the path
            String path = FileUtils.getPath(this, uri);
            Log.d(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
            // Get the file instance
            // File file = new File(path);
            // Initiate the upload
        }
        break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The `getPath()` method in my `FileUtils.java` is:

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { "_data" };
        Cursor cursor = null;

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_data");
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Eat it
        }
    }
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```